# Use of ¿? in the Following Sentence

Tags: gramática

En la siguiente oración, ¿debe tener "¿?" para la última parte?

*Para empezar la lección, la profesora levanta una gran bolsa de corazones de caramelo y le pregunta a los niños, en su experiencia previa, que saben de ellos.*

No sé si la siguiente versión es mejor.

*Para empezar la lección, la profesora levanta una gran bolsa de corazones de caramelo y le pregunta a los niños, en su experiencia previa, ¿qué saben de ellos?*

---

In the following sentence, should there be "¿?" around the last part?

*Para empezar la lección, la profesora levanta una gran bolsa de corazones de caramelo y le pregunta a los niños, en su experiencia previa, que saben de ellos.*

Is the following version better?

*Para empezar la lección, la profesora levanta una gran bolsa de corazones de caramelo y le pregunta a los niños, en su experiencia previa, ¿qué saben de ellos?*

Answer (score 12):

Yo propondría las siguientes variantes: como oración subordinada:

> Para empezar la lección, la profesora levanta una gran bolsa de corazones de caramelo y les pregunta a los niños, en su experiencia previa, **qué** saben ellos.

O como cita textual:

> Para empezar la lección, la profesora levanta una gran bolsa de corazones de caramelo y les pregunta a los niños: «En su experiencia previa, ¿qué saben ustedes de ellos?»

(O en España: *En vuestra experiencia previa, ¿qué sabeis vosotros de ellos?*)

En la cláusula subordinada no van los símbolos de interrogación, pero se usa el pronombre interrogativo *qué* (con acento explícito) en lugar del conector *que*.

Comment: ¿Por qué los símbolos de interrogación no van en una cláusula subordinada? ¿Puedes darme una fuente donde se refiere eso? Yo sé los símbolos de exclamación pueden quedar en las clásulas subordinadas.

Comment: @Dombey: es similar en otras lenguas europeas: (_I wonder what she said_) y creo que la lógica es que la cláusula subordinada no es una pregunta sino un objeto, en este caso de una oración declarativa.

Comment: De acuerdo. La diferencia es más notable si cambiamos los tiempos. "Les preguntó : «¿qué saben ustedes?»" y "Les preguntó qué sabían." O "Le pregunté dónde vivía" y "Le pregunté «¿Dónde vives?»"

Comment: De paso: yo ubicaría "en su experiencia previa" al final de la oración, para destacar que forma parte de la pregunta: "le pregunta a los niños qué saben ellos, en su experiencia previa".

Comment: Además de lo que dice (correctamente) esta respuesta, el pronombre *le* está mal usado. Debería ser *les* (concuerda con *los niños*) o, simplemente, se puede eliminar.